# Breakpoint-sass not loading in gulp setup, Susy is working fine

Tags: npm, gulp, susy, susy-sass, breakpoint-sass

Hi I'm trying to get breakpoint-sass working with susy in my Gulp set-up

I have ran npm install breakpoint-sass --save-dev and linked it to the top of my sass file with  @import "./node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/breakpoint"; (susy is working fine from @import "./node_modules/susy/sass/susy";)

my gulp sass task is this

```
gulp.task("styles", function() {
return gulp.src("scss/application.scss")
    .pipe( bulkSass())
    .pipe(maps.init())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'compressed',
        includePaths: ['node_modules/susy/sass', 'node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/breakpoint'],
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(maps.write('./'))
    //.pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/'))
    .pipe(reload({stream:true}))
});
```

and my scss partial

```
@import "./node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/breakpoint";
@import "./node_modules/susy/sass/susy";

  #main {
    @include span(12);
    background: $primary-color;
    text-align: center;
       h1 {
        color: green;
        height: 2em;
       }

        @include breakpoint(500px){
          h1{
            color: red;
       }

    }

 }
```

the h1 tag is red at all screen widths and never green. I can't see why this is happening. I have used breakpoint before in a grunt project with ruby and had no issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your `includePath` for breakpoint is one level too deep, omit the trailing `/breakpoint` so that it looks like so:

```
includePaths: ['node_modules/susy/sass', 'node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets'],
```

Once the `includePath` is set there is no need to specify the full path in the `@import` because gulp already knows where to look. So you can reduce your `@import`s to:

```
@import "breakpoint";
@import "susy";
```

Its always a good point to look into the compiled css if things don't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks – just one small tweak to suggest for anyone who tried the good solution by @zisoft and couldn't get it to work, I used `'./node_modules/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets'` with success, where without the `./` in front it would fail. Maybe obvious to some people, but wanted to make a note.